# Android remove MarkerOptions(!) from Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm adding my position to map using MarkerOptions as follows:

```
userMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location");
mMap.addMarker(userMarker);
```

How could it remove it from the map?

Back in the old days, Marker Class had a remove() method, but MarkerOptions has nothing similar... I also checked mMap (which is a GoogleMap), but no luck... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `addMarker()` method returns a `Marker` object that you can work with:

```
userMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location");
Marker myMarker = mMap.addMarker(userMarker);
```

And then remove your `Marker` doing

```
myMarker.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `MarkerOptions` class has a few methods that could help you like:

```
public MarkerOptions visible(boolean visible);
```

This basically sets visibility status of your marker.

```
MarkerOptions updatedMarker = userMarker.visible(false);
```

It also returns the `MarkerOptions` object with its new status updated!

You can find more information on this by clicking [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions).

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Marker` class has a `remove` method.
Simply call: `marker.remove()`